# Server throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I have a java based server that suppose to be **not** a memory intensive. 
The server is running in debug mode (using the jvm -Xdebug flag).

I just wonder if running a java application in such a (debug) mode might cause to an OutOfMemoryError?

Thanks
Guy

Answer (score 0):

what do you use that flag for? Remote debugging? Well there could be a debugger attached, that is holding onto memory objects, and there can be additional memory and cpu overhead by doing so, but usually not to that extend that it creates OutOfMemoryErrors.

For a first stab, activate -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError and have a look at the dump file generated with Eclipse MAT. Then you will see what is consuming the memory and can plan your next steps.